# Accelerometer output mA/g; how to get to mV/g?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, accelerometer

Using a Q-Flex QA2000-030 accelerometer that has output of current. It has a scale factor of 1.2 mA/g. If I want to get the output as 0.1 V/g-- how should I go about making the change? Would an op-amp current to voltage work to change the output? How do I introduce the scale factor to get 0.1V/g?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert from voltage to current, you simply feed the current through a resistor to some reference voltage (e.g. GND) and measure the voltage across the resistor.

You have an output of \$1.2\space[\mathrm{mA/g}]\$, which you want to map to \$0.1\space[\mathrm{V/g}]\$, so that means you need a ratio of:

$$\frac{0.1\space[\mathrm{V/g}]}{1.2\space[\mathrm{mA/g}]}$$

Nicely, we know from Ohms law, \$V = I\times R\$, so \$R = \frac{V}{I}\$ which doing unit cancellation we see is exactly the same units as the above ratio. So:

$$ R = \frac{V}{I} = \frac{0.1\space[\mathrm{V}]}{1.2\space[\mathrm{mA}]} = 0.0833\space[\mathrm{k\Omega}] = 83.3\space[\mathrm{\Omega}]$$

Thus feeding the output current from your accelerometer into an \$83.3\space[\mathrm{\Omega}]\$ resistor will give you a voltage drop of the desired output. This is not a standard value, but you could use say {\$78.7\space[\mathrm{\Omega}]\$ in series with \$4.64\space[\mathrm{\Omega}]\$}, or go for {\$2.2\space[\mathrm{k\Omega}]\$ in parallel with \$86.6\space[\mathrm{\Omega}]\$}, or one of many other combinations.

Depending on the chip, you may find that it is not exactly \$1.2\space[\mathrm{mA/g}]\$. If you need to be able to adjust the ratio to compensate for the sensor not being exact, you can either do that digitally (scale the measured value), or vary the resistance value.

For example replace the \$2.2\space[\mathrm{k\Omega}]\$ resistor in the parallel example above with a \$4.7\space[\mathrm{k\Omega}]\$ trimmer resistor perhaps with a \$220\space[\mathrm{\Omega}]\$ fixed resistor to get a nice trimming range (\$62.1\space[\mathrm{\Omega}]\$ to \$85.1\space[\mathrm{\Omega}]\$). This would cover the \$1.2\space[\mathrm{mA/g}]\$ to \$1.46\space[\mathrm{mA/g}]\$ range given in the datasheet plus a bit more in each direction.

[image: Tunable Circuit]

If you need to measure this with an ADC, you could then, depending on your ADC input impedance, buffer this voltage using a unity-gain op-amp.

Comment: If using the trimmer resistor method the use of a precision resistor (as 86.6 Ω above) is actually unnecessary. Use a standard value resistor values and re-calculate the parallel/series arrangement to come close to the center of the 0.1 V/g point. For the calculation assume that the trimmer resistor is set to it's mid-range position.

Comment: Or you could just use an [83.5 Ω resistor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/koa-speer-electronics-inc/RN73R1ETTP83R5C25/10007297), which *is* a standard value and is well within the actual tolerance on the (rather poorly-controlled) scale factor anyway. It's only in the E192 series, so availability and price are a bit worse than your average standard resistor, but you can still get them, and 7¢ each (in quantity) is hardly going to break the bank.

Comment: If an ADC system is to be used there are other issues. With a max input of 60 g, a conversion of 0.1 V/g, the max output is 6 V, too high for a standard 5 V ADC. The 60 g input is actually listed as ±60 g, so it seems the output is actually bipolar. A required bipolar power supply seems to support this too. So a converted output would be ±6 V. With all that taken into account using a shunt resistor of 28.53 ohms would give a max output of ±2.5 V, which if given an offset of +2.5 V would yield a 0-5 V ADC input. Also, with a max output of 87.6 mA the resistor wattage is a potential issue.

Answer (score 3):

You add a resistor of appropriate value to ground.

Note that the scale factor is not well controlled- it's actually the current through an internal coil used to balance the accelerometer so it varies significantly from unit-to-unit due to manufacturing tolerances.

If it was exactly 1.2mA/g then you'd want a resistor of 0.1V/0.0012A = 83.3Ω.

You have to consider the compliance of the source if the output voltage gets too high in relation to the power supply rails, and there are some subtle secondary effects that you may not have to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

The brochure for this device [Q-FlexQA-2000Accelerometer](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/content/dam/aerobt/en/documents/learn/products/sensors/brochures/Q-FlexQA-2000Accelerometer_bro.pdf) says:

> The integral electronics develops an acceleration-proportional output current
> providing both static and dynamic acceleration measurement. By use of customer
> supplied output load resistor, appropriately scaled for the acceleration range of
> the application, the output current can be converted into a voltage.

If you want 1.2 mA and 0.1 V, Mr Ohm says 0.1/0.0012 = 83 Ω

The [FAQ](https://ko.innalabs.co.kr/support/frequently-asked-questions/) suggests you need to take into account the coil resistance; it also has pinout and diagram.